# Submit formulário com arquivo

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```js
<form [formGroup]="notifForm">
      <div class="box-body">
          <app-input errorMessage="Preencha a Descrição" [showTip]="false">
                 <label for="descricao">Título</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Descrição" minlength="5" formControlName="descricao">
                     </app-input>

                      <app-input errorMessage="É obrigatório adicionar arquivo" [showTip]="false">
                          <label for="arquivo">Anexar arquivos</label>
                          <input type="file"  formControlName="arquivo" multiple (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
                      </app-input>    
                   </div>
      <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="notifForm.invalid" (click)="enviar()">Submit</button>
      </div>
 </form>
```

Estou fazendo o envio assim:

```js
this.notificationService.save( this.notifForm.value )
                              .subscribe( r => {
                                  message.message = 'Cadastrado com sucesso!'
                                  message.status = true
                                  this.notificationService.notify( message )
                                  this.router.navigate(['/notificacao/notificacao'])
                              }, err => {
                                message.message = 'Houve problema ao tentar salvar!'
                                message.status = false
                                console.error('Erro', err.message);
                                this.notificationService.notify( message )
                              })
```

No node estou recebendo os dados assim:

```
notificacaoRouter.post( `${prefix}/save`, async (req: any, res, next)=>{     
    console.log(req.body);  
    next()
})
```

O resultado está saindo assim:

```
{ descricao: 'sdfdsfd',
      detalhe: 'fdfdfd',
      arquivo: 'C:\\fakepath\\linda.jpg' 
    }
```

Eu envio dois arquivos e só recebo um arquivo.

Eu gostaria de ler todos e gostaria de saber como copiar esse arquivo para uma pasta específica

Eu configurei isso aqui

```
import * as multipart from 'connect-multiparty'
const multipartMiddleware = multipart({uploadDir: './public'})
```

Mas não sei como usar...

Vi muitos tutoriais que só ensinam a fazer o upload de um único arquivo e não do formulário contendo o texto.